# CartoDB Core with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, carto

I just recently experimented with CartoDB. I have an existing Leaflet Map with lots of Plugins and dependencies. Just adding the CartoDB.js does not work (I think there is a version conflict, but I am not sure - I think it does not work with L.Control).

Therefore, I was wondering if it's possible to just use the CartoDB Core with leaflet. I only want to show layers I created with CartoDB. Popups for the layer would be super, but not mandatory.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

CartoDB.js includes Leaflet already, so it's possible that you have some conflicts there.

You can use this URL to get CartoDB.js without Leaflet included: http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb_noleaflet.js

Comment: Thanks, I tried with that lib. The problem is that the noleaflet seems to require several dependencies except leaflet. I needed to add underscore and Backbone, but still I get an exception when excuting the library: `cartodb_noleaflet.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. The map I pass to cartodb is not undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it say somewhere what version of leaflet is included in cartoDB.js?